# R plot implicit function outer command

Tags: r

I would like to plot an implicit function of x and y:  `1 - 0.125 * y ^ 2 - x ^ 2 = 0.005`
I know it can be plotted as a contour plot but have trouble with the "outer" command 
in the following:

`x<-seq(0.4,1.01,length=1000)

    y<-seq(0,3,length=1000)

    z<-outer(x,y,FUN="1-0.125*y^2-x^2=0.005")

    contour(x,y,z,levels=0,drawpoints=FALSE)`

I read the FAQ (7.17) regarding the "outer" command and the need to vectorize the function but am still in a quandry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're a little confused about the meaning of 'function'.
All the operations (+,-,^) in your function are vectorized so that all works just fine.

```
x <- seq(0.4,1.01,length=1000)
y <- seq(0,3,length=1000)
z <- outer(x,y,function(x,y) 1-0.125*y^2-x^2-0.005)
contour(x,y,z,levels=0,drawlabels=FALSE)
```

Or if you want a minor shortcut:

```
library(emdbook)
curve3d(1-0.125*y^2-x^2-0.005,
        xlim=c(0.4,1.01),
        ylim=c(0,3),
        n=c(100,100),
        sys3d="contour",drawlabels=FALSE,levels=0)
```

This actually is slower because it uses a `for` loop internally rather than `outer()`, so I set it to 100x100 rather than 1000x1000 (which is overkill for this example anyway), but it will work on more complex examples that can't be vectorized easily ...

Comment: Hi Ben, Thank you for your solution and for explaining my mistake. Best wishes, Carey

Comment: Just a follow-up question.  When the above code is run the first point appears as a small data point circle separated from the rest of the line.  Any ideas on how to correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your interpretation of that incorrect. That is a "0" and it labels the level represented by the curve. Ben only asked for one level and that was "0". That probably would have been more apparent if you had used: `contour(x,y,z,levels=seq(-1,1,by=0.1))`. You could also have used z<-outer(x,y,function(x,y) 1-0.125*y^2-x^2) and set the level=0.005

Comment: I found that adding `drawlabels=FALSE` to the contour statement turns off display of the contour level label.

Answer (score 1):

plotting an implicit equation as a contour plot is overkill. You are essentially throwing away 99.99% of the computations you did.

Better way is to find the value of y for a given x that will make the equation 0. Here is the code using uniroot in base R.

## R code using uniroot from base R

```
x = seq(0, 0.995, length = 100) # no real root above x = 0.995
root <- function(a) {
        uniroot(function(x,y) 1 - 0.125 * y^2 - x^2 - 0.005, c(0, 3), x = a )$root #only care about the root
} 
y <- sapply(x, root)
plot(x,y, type = "l")
```

Ok the c(0, 3) in the uniroot argument is the range of y values where the root lies. so for every given x value uniroot will look for a y value between 0 and 3 for a root.

## R code using fsolve from pracma package

```
library("pracma")
x <- seq(0,0.995, length=100)
fun <- function(y) c(1 - 0.125 * y^2 - x^2 - 0.005)
y_sol <- fsolve(fun, rep(1, length(x)))$x
plot(x,y_sol, type="l")
```

fsolve takes in the function whose root is sought and guess values of y for every given value of x. Here we are saying that the y values lie near 1. we are giving it a guess value of 1's

uniroot wants a bound range to look for root, fsolve requires a guess where the root might be.

These are faster ways to plot implicit equations. You can then use any graph package like ggplot2/rbokeh to do the plotting.

I haven't done any benchmarks so cannot tell which one method is faster. Though for such a simple implicit function it won't matter