# How to add ellipse plane to 3D plot in R

Tags: r

R code about plot plane z = x+y：

```
library("rgl")
f <- function(x,y) 
x+y

x_grid <- seq(0,1, length=20)
y_grid <- x_grid 
z_grid <- outer(x_grid, y_grid, f)
surface3d(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid,front="line",back="line")
axes3d()
```

R code about plot ellipse 5x^2-4xy+5y^2=1：

```
my.fun <- function(x,y){5*x^2 - 4*x*y + 5*y^2}
x<-seq(-sqrt(5/21), sqrt(5/21), length.out = 101)
y<-seq(-sqrt(5/21), sqrt(5/21), length.out = 101)
z<-outer(x,y,my.fun)
contour(x, y, z, levels = 1, drawlabels = 0, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
```

How to add ellipse plane to 3D plot in R? Thanks!

Comment: This answers the question about how to do it in 2d, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702248/plotting-implicit-function ... and at the moment it is a 2d function, so the request to do it with rgl is not making a lot of sense. The contour function is not going to be able to write to an RGL window.

Comment: Your function `my.fun(...)` defines a parabolic ellipsoid, not an ellipse. Do you want the intersection of the parabolic ellipsoid and the plane in 3d?? Or do you just want to plot both the ellipsoid and the plane together in a single 3d plot?

Comment: surface3d(x_grid, y_grid, z_grid,front="line",back="line") is not ellipse plane,I need ellipse plane in 3D plot.

Comment: 3D plot like:http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/ellipse3d-d0e273.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not sure what you are trying to do, but this plots the intersection of your plane

> z = x + y

and your parabolic ellipsoid

> z = 5x<sup>2</sup> -4xy + 5y<sup>2</sup>

and colors the resulting ellipse as in your linked image.

```
library(rgl)
f      <- function(x,y) x+y
my.fun <- function(x,y) 5*x^2 - 4*x*y + 5*y^2

x_grid <- seq(0,1, length=20)
z_grid <- outer(x_grid, x_grid, f)

theta <- seq(0,2*pi,length=1000)
r     <- sqrt(5/21)
df    <- expand.grid(x=r*cos(theta),y=r*cos(theta))
df$z  <- with(df,f(x,y) - my.fun(x,y))
xyz   <- df[df$z>=0,]
surface3d(x_grid, x_grid, z_grid, front="line",back="line")
axes3d() 
zlim    <- range(-1000*f(xyz$x,xyz$y))
zlen    <- diff(zlim) + 1
palette <- heat.colors(zlen)                       
col     <- palette[-1000*f(xyz$x,xyz$y)-zlim[1]+1 ]
with(xyz,points3d(x,y,f(x,y),color=col))
```

[image]

This uses a quick and dirty approach to calculating the intersection of the plane and the ellipsoid: create a relatively fine grid of points in (x,y) and then simply identify all the points where `f(x,y) - my.fun(x,y) < 0`. These points are inside the ellipse formed by the intersection. Then just plot those points.

The idiomatic way to do this, I think, is using `ploygon3d(...)` but when I tried that the function did not converge...

**EDIT** Response to OP's comment.

So this plots the intersection of your parabolic ellipsoid with the place `z = 1` and colors the result based on increasing values of x (which looks like the image you provided). I have no idea what the point of this is...

```
library(rgl)
f      <- function(x,y) rep(1,length(x))
my.fun <- function(x,y) 5*x^2 - 4*x*y + 5*y^2

x_grid <- seq(0,1, length=20)
z_grid <- outer(x_grid, x_grid, f)

theta <- seq(0,2*pi,length=1000)
r     <- sqrt(5/21)
df    <- expand.grid(x=r*cos(theta),y=r*cos(theta))
df$z  <- with(df,f(x,y) - my.fun(x,y))
xyz   <- df[df$z>=0,]
surface3d(x_grid, x_grid, z_grid, front="line",back="line")
axes3d() 
zlim    <- range(-1000*xyz$x)
zlen    <- diff(zlim) + 1
palette <- heat.colors(zlen)               # height color lookup table
col     <- palette[-1000*xyz$x-zlim[1]+1 ] # assign colors to heights for each point
with(xyz,points3d(x,y,f(x,y),color=col))
```

Comment: Many thanks. Can you make the plane and the ellipsoid parallel to XY plane?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172666/how-to-specify-z-axis-range-and-add-add-circle-or-ellipse-in-3d-plot-in-r I want to add ellipsoid plane in this 3D plot. Thanks.

Comment: If that's what you want, then what is the point of plotting the plane `z = x + y`??

Comment: I hope the z=0.1 plane(parallel to XY plane),but I don't know the plane equation.

Comment: Create a relatively fine grid of points in (x,y) and then simply identify all the points where f(x,y) - my.fun(x,y) < 0. I don't really understand. Can you explain in detail? Thanks.